# How to interface two arduino board readings with a C program?

Tags: arduino

I have two microphones, each I want to sample at maximum sampling rate. However, if I attach two microphones both to the same arduino board to two analog inputs, the readings are interfering with each other and results are useless.

So, I decided to use two arduino boards to fetch two microphones. One arduino board only samples one microphone. I want to do some calculations with both of the mic recordings, so I need to write a framework to interface with both arduinos (through USBs) to read their serial data.

I need to write the framework in C, but I couldn't find any sample code online. I have already seen a lot "Arduino codes", but that's not what I am looking for. Can anyone tell me how I can interface with a arduino board?

Comment: Why not use a multichannel I2C/SPI ADC instead?

Comment: What is exactly is that? Can you please show me an example?

Comment: http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/data-converters/precision-adc-less-10msps-products.page#p158=Serial%20SPI;SPI;Serial%20I2C;Serial&p1028=2;2

Comment: I am not looking for a low level component, I am looking a straight forward solution for the problem I am dealing with.

Comment: The component *is* the straightforward solution.

Answer (score 0):

Do both microphones come with their own adc? if so, that should get rid of some of the interference.
also check out. http://linuxhaxor.blogspot.com/2009/07/first-shot-at-noise-cancellation-has.html
No one knows if this has been tested but it looks like it should work.